# Invalid usage of id selector '#block-tb-megamenu-menu-menu-hudmain-v2021'. Try using a class selector or some other selector

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a webpage. I got some code from one another web portal and I want to implement that code in my portal. When saving the file I am getting this error:

> Invalid usage of id selector
> '#block-tb-megamenu-menu-menu-hudmain-v2021'. Try using a class
> selector or some other selector.

HTML Tag:

```
<section id="block-tb-megamenu-menu-menu-hudmain-v2021"
                            class="block block-tb-megamenu clearfix">
</section>
```

CSS Tag:

```
section#block-tb-megamenu-menu-menu-hudmain-v2021 .tb-megamenu .nav > li > a {
  background-color: #163667;
}
```

[image]

can some one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: The markup you provided in itself doesn't seem to contain syntactic errors. CSS selectors won't result in errors in any browser because invalid CSS rules simply get ignored and fail gracefully. Where are you getting this error message from? What is this _portal_ are you referring to?

Comment: Hi, @BumhanYu thanks for your reply. I am using this in salesforce "Lightning Web Component"

Comment: As @BumhanYu mentioned, CSS itself can't and won't throw errors. What framework/library are you using?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals that _"No support for ID selectors in CSS. ... When the template is rendered, id values may be transformed into globally unique values. If you use an ID selector in CSS, it won’t match the transformed."_ (according to [Salesforce's official documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css). There you have it, as the error states. `ID` selectors are not selected. Use a different selector.

Comment: any alternative for <selection id=> tag @BumhanYu

Comment: I'd have to suggest you do some basic research about how CSS selectors work. You can target an element by a myriad of ways (e.g. generic element tag, `id`,  `class`, `data-` attribute, adjacency, etc). I simply cannot recommend a silver bullet alternative to an `ID` selector without context.